# Nuget.targets: error could not find a part of the path

Tags: msbuild, nuget, teamcity

I trying the build a website via TeamCity. It is a three stage process. The first two restore NuGet packages and the third builds the website.

[image]

Here is also the build steps for step 3.

[image]

The first one passes with this only warning

```
Step 1/3: Restore the NuGet Packages for BalanceToBuy (NuGet Installer) (3s)
[10:22:43][Step 1/3] scan: Searching for nuget.config files
[10:22:43][scan] RepositoryPath was not extracted from NuGet.config file at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.Config. Packages will be downloaded into default path: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\packages.
[10:22:43][scan] Found packages folder: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\packages
[10:22:43][scan] No repositories.config found at C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\packages\repositories.config
[10:22:43][scan] Failed to resolve project reference from solution file: Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "http://localhost:66", "http://localhost:66", "{72D2746B-946D-4670-AB52-C087971DB810}"
```

The second one passes and the tird error our with these messages (22 of them)

```
[10:22:51][Buy.Business\Buy.Business.csproj] RestorePackages
[10:22:51][RestorePackages] Exec
[10:22:51][Exec] "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\Buy.Business\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ "
[10:22:52][Exec] Restoring NuGet packages...
[10:22:52][Exec] To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
[10:22:52][Exec] EXEC 'Dapper' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
[10:22:52][Exec] Installing 'log4net 2.0.8'.
[10:22:52][Exec] Installing 'Dapper 1.60.6'.
[10:22:52][Exec] Successfully installed 'log4net 2.0.8'.
[10:22:52][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): 'Dapper' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
[10:22:52][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): The 'Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.2' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60717.93'.
[10:22:52][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\BalanceToBuy.Business\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ "" exited with code 1.
```

I fixed that problem by manually going to the CLI and updated the NuGet.exe it goes from version to to verions 5. I tried running it again and now I get a strange error.

```
[11:46:44][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): Could not find a part of the path 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ \packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0'.
[11:46:44][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): Could not find a part of the path 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ \packages\FastMember.Signed.1.3.0'.
[11:46:44][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): Could not find a part of the path 'C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ \packages\EntityFramework.6.2.0'.
[11:46:44][Exec] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.targets(100, 9): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\BalanceToBuy.Utility\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ "" exited with code 1.
```

I noticed that there is a space in the `-solutionDir "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a606a53a0957ca4b\ "`
**How is that getting there?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This issue should have been solved in March](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7657#issuecomment-469901706). I'm surprised you'd get it now, as it implies that you created your solution (With VS2010, 2012 or 2013) between the 20th of December 2018 and the 5th of March 2019, but only just updated to a newer `nuget.exe` now. Anyway, if you want to keep using this old, outdated way of doing NuGet restores, you need to manually edit your `nuget.targets` file as I wrote in the GitHub issue.

However, I still recommend [migrating to automatic package restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#migrate-to-automatic-package-restore-visual-studio). It means you'll need an extra step in your CI pipeline to do the restore before building, but Visual Studio 2015 onwards no longer has functionality to add NuGet restore in the way that your solution is doing.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do it with the link you provided. This is really my first time using this technology. Thank you. If you see anything Im doing wrong please let me know!

Comment: I know there's a lot to learn, but we already have [docs with quickstart guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio). I suggest starting there.

Comment: Thank you that helped allot. Yous said I needed an extra step in the CI pipleline. What would the step be?

Comment: usually people download nuget.exe (or check it into their repository) and run `nuget restore`. If all the projects in your project use `PackageReference` (definately not unless you're using VS2017 or higher) then you can use `msbuild -t:restore`, or if all projects are SDK style (.NET Core), then you can use `dotnet restore`.

Comment: I think I'm stuck with just using NuGet restore. I have 20 or so csproj that are in an older format. They where created with visual studio 2012 or so.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me...

On Visual Studio setting (Tools -> Options), I cleared the NuGet cache and changed the option "Default package management format" from "Packages.config" to "PackageReference"

[image]

Comment: I tried that to fix the same error I had pointing to _C:\...[project-name]\tests\...MigrationService.UnitTests\obj\Debug\net6.0_ and _C:\...[project-name]...\...MigrationService.UnitTests.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig'_.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had initially released the library and later altered certain directories and file locations. My library icon and license were initially stored in ../../../Downloads. However, after restructuring the folder, I neglected to update the file paths and tried to pack the library. To address this issue, I navigated to the project properties, accessed the Package settings, and updated the file locations to ../../../../../Downloads.