# VS2022 Nuget Restore package missing project directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have a Visual Studio web application (.NET 4.51) that I am trying to build on Azure DevOps Server (on-prem) 2019 - the solution uses a GIT repository.  The solution folder contains a half dozen projects, mainly class libraries and one web project. It builds fine both on the dev machine and on the build server when done through Visual Studio.

The build pipeline is a very basic ASP.Net one consisting of Get sources, Use NuGet, Build Solution with the error occurring in the build solution phase.

It is using NuGet 6.7.0 and in the build-step is checking the NuGet packages for each project.

For the packages that don't exist I get

```
Restoring Autofac 3.5.2
Adding package Autofac 3.5.2 to folder d:\...\mysolution\ \packages
```

The issue is that there is a space where the project name should be and the packages directory.  NuGet then throws an error: '*Could not find part of the path...*

Am wondering if anyone know how to go about fix this, or where the missing setting may be found?

Comment: Maybe you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58716835/16162444) or [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7657#issuecomment-469901706),  and check if you are using the `NuGet.targets` files in your project, it seems the same issue.